# How does the paralyzing device used on Tony Stark work?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-2008

The answer by @Bevan to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20130/why-did-tony-stark-become-lethargic-when-his-arc-reactor-was-removed?rq=1) made me wonder: **how exactly does the paralyzing device used by Obadiah work ?**

*I'll take the liberty of re-using his screenshot here.*
[image]

As mentioned in the above question and answers, this is seen used in the first Iron Man movie.  It obviously operates in a 'sonic' way, as Obadiah uses some kind of noise-cancelling ear plugs if you will, so he is not affected by it.
But how can the device have such a big effect ?  I can understand that sound can make you very uncomfortable, but weakening and disabling a person (for a prolonged time) entirely ... ?

The black, vein-like stuff that appears on Tony's face, I'll just take as extra dramatic effect for cinematic purposes.

*Although I'm primarily familiar with the movies' canon, any other canon will do as well.*

Comment: Through magic of course

Comment: More than a few people have asked why such a device hasn't been used against, say, the Hulk, at the very least. I doubt the secret of its creation died with Stane.

Comment: Note to VtCers: It doesn't sound like the OP is looking for a full scientific explanation, just an in-universe explanation. That, I believe, would be on-topic. Note the request for a canonical source, as opposed to say a scientific paper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Militaries and businesses have been experimenting with sound based weapons for years.  Some are even already in use commercially, such as those used by some cruise ship lines to ward off pirates.  There are various effects that have been demonstrated to be possible, such as one device that works by operating at a frequency that causes a person's eyeballs to vibrate making their vision blurry and distorted.  There are others that can effectively paralyze people, but most "real world" versions currently do that by causing the person excruciating pain.  It's not beyond the realm of reality that a less painful, but still effective version could be developed in the near future.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_weapon) and [here](http://stardefense.blogspot.com/2012/05/sonic-weapons-and-crowd-control.html) for more on these concepts.

Comment: The devices used by cruise ships (and in many other situations) is the LRAD, a directed-sound device designed to be intolerably loud to anyone in front of it while being perfectly safe to the guy right behind it. The only physical effects the device has, however, is pain based on the extreme sound pressure levels.

Comment: Device that makes eyeballs vibrate? God damn if you tune it up, they would be popping like popcorn. Jesus Christ

Answer (score 4):

I think the basic idea of the Iron Man device is that some particular frequency or combination of them will cause a disruption in the brain that causes the person's muscles to tense uncontrollably while they are exposed to the sound, and for a short period thereafter (hence the dark lines; those are veins sticking out as every muscle in the body tenses to the limit). It's just plausible enough to be believable, but the idea's also simple enough that someone must have tried it and determined it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I thought the device somehow caused all of the blood in his veins to congeal. That explains the black veins around the area where the device was used and his paleness afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This device can probably send vibrations thru your ear into your brain. The device probably vibrates the cerebrum which this part of your brain controls your voluntary muscle movements. It probably just sends this part of the brain into shock for about 15 or so minutes.